# Is there an HTML way to indicate that an attribute value is "temporary" (until Javascript changes it)?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, w3c

I have a SVG element `feTurbulence`, and I want to put a random value for its `seed`. So I've set the `seed` attribute value to `0` in the HTML the browser downloads, and put a JS code to change it afterward `document.querySelector('feTurbulence').setAttribute('seed', Math.random())`. But when loading the HTML, the browser has no clue that the `seed` will change "soon" (ie: it is useless to render this SVG, because it will soon change).

So my question is: **is there an HTML way to declare to the browser that the attribute value will change soon** (and so, let the browser be smart enough to not render the whole SVG before the seed had changed)?

I remember having read something about that "the attribute value will change soon" in HTML specs or so, but I cannot find the exact source it was.

Comment: i dont think that exists.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just hide the element until you change the seed?

Comment: Or use a data binding framework and only display the item when it is available, or when it is fully changed.

Comment: @DanielA.White Ah, indeed, I guess I've mixed with the CSS `will-change` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change I might try it then

Comment: @CodyG. Because that would be far more imperative-oriented rather than declarative, which I prefer for its "let the browser be smart for you" approach.

Comment: Aren't you taking an imperative approach anyway, by manually setting the seed later after the page has loaded?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau If there was a way to declare `put a random value as this attribute value` then I wouldn't need imperative. IMO, it's not a problem to have imperative stuff for business-logic related things (bc spec cannot handle all business cases) but the optimisation is more a system logic, and there, I prefer to rely on the browser as most as possible. So I guess I'll just not optimize anything (I'm just happy to have found again that `will-change`).

Comment: @Xenos you could self-answer this, since there's no better answer than "there's will-change, but it doesn't apply here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I've mixed with CSS [`will-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) property.

I'll just let things as is, with a seed of `0`, replace it by a `Math.random()` once `DOMContentLoaded` is fired, and let the browser decide whether the SVG is rendered twice or not.